# Spring Boot overriding YML profile from Command Line

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I wan't to override an existing YML file profile using command line, so I did this.

1. Created a folder and added to the classpath
2. Copied another application.yml in that new folder
3. Ran this command `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=unit-test`

but it still picking up the "default" active profile from the source code application.yml. I also tried creating a application.properties instead of application.yml but it still didn't get picked up?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class SuchApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private DogeService dogeService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println("AutoConfiguration should have wired up our stuff");
        System.out.println("Let's see if we are doge-worthy...");
        if (dogeService.requiresDogeness()) {
            System.out.println(dogeService.leDoge());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Doge for us :(");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SuchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have the following YML file under my **resources** folder

```
spring:
  profiles.active: default
---
spring:
  profiles: default

doge:
  wow: 10
  such: so
  very: true

---
spring:
   profiles: unit-test
doge:
  wow: 4
  such: so
  very: true
```

Comment: Your yml file also has `spring.profiles.active` which interferes with the one passed in from the command line, remove the one from the yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Spring Boot and resolved it with this annotation in my configuration class...

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
```

But from the official Spring documentation, this annotation looks unnecessary, which is why I did not add on the first attempt.